# How to customize / edit the filter presets in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, filter, configuration

Are the filters presets unchangeable or are there ways to customize their values?

For example, maybe change their strength or the direction of the bevel.

How can I alter the filter presets in Inkscape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit those filter presets once applied on an object using Filters- Filter editor(refer image). Vary the settings to get desired result.
[image]

Change the effect parameters & you can view the live changes in an object.

Comment: Great thank you. I will mark correct when the time runs out